# android issues not converting all fetched phone contacts numbers into json format

Tags: android, json

I have fetched all *contacts* number from *`Android phone`* But not converting all `phonenumbers` in to `json` format. In some `*android phone*` ,it is working but in my phone *Samsung Duos* ,**it is not working**.
 It gives output like that:-

{"data":[{"phone":"+9187678965433","name":"Home"},{"phone":"+9178961042","name":"Vikash(bang)"},{"phone":"+91826543748","name":"Chandan(mota)"},{"phone":"+91867868199","name":"Amit Singh"},{"phone":"+9143228811","name":"Jimmi Sinha"},{"phone":"+91989769610","name":"Nagar(Aone)"},{"phone":"+919465436261","name":"Shahi(Biet)"},{"phone":"+917576540555","name":"Pankaj(Biet)"},"name":"P

Some of my code below:-
After it stores in bytearray first it prepares json format.while converting contacts to json format,json breaks as shown above

some of my code below:-

```
JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
          JSONObject json = null;
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

        Cursor people =getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

        people.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String name   =people.getString(indexName);
            String number =people.getString(indexNumber);
            HashMap<String,Object> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            NamePhoneType.put("name",name);
            NamePhoneType.put("mobileno",number);
            //test email
    //        NamePhoneType.put("email","asad@test.com");
            //test email ends here
            Log.d("name+---+number",name+"----"+number);
//            userarraylist.add(NamePhoneType);
            json =  new JSONObject().put("contact_no",number.trim());
            postjson.put(json);

            json.put("name",name.trim());
            postjson.put(json);
        } while (people.moveToNext());
         Log.d("json data new query",postjson.toString().trim());
          people.close();
```

Comment: and where is your output

Comment: i have addedd my output.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is correct. It just looks like that your logcat is truncating the output. This is due the maximum length of 4*1024 bytes.

You can increase that but its not recommend due speed and readable outputs.

Where is the error you are getting? It looks like that you have an Array called data which contains jsonobjects with phone and name.

If you cant to modify the logcat in AS go to

file-> Settings-> Editor-> Colors & Font -> Console Font

Comment: I m not any getting error.Just my json gets break as shown in the above output.

Comment: Logcat issue. Ignore that. If you want to display the whole logcat check the modified post

Comment: How to check modified post.Sry,I m not getting.

Comment: Actually i have stuck here for a week.I m not getting the solution for this.I've tried a lot.I don't know where i m getting wrong?

Comment: show some code. If its not the logcat (output) its for sure something like byte[] which is not big enough to store your data.

Comment: i have added the code above,now you can see.I m first converting contacts into json format at that time my log i.e postjson.tostring.trim() shows the results where the contacts in json format appears to be broke as shown above

Comment: as i thought. It's in your json object but Log.d() does only display a limited length of the content. If you want to display everything in your jsonobject split it. for (int i = 0; i <= putjson.length(); i++) { Log.d("data", putjson.getJsonObject(i)); }

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Index 1326 out of range .this exception is coming when i m adding the code and running

Comment: int i =0; i< putjson.length(); i++. Please try to understand the code.

Comment: can u change my code and add in comments.it will be best for me to understand.becoz i m not getting.

Comment: check the sample at the end of the site: http://www.informatik-blog.com/json-einfach-erklaert-bearbeitet-erstellt-und-ausgelesen/